# How to use created C++ module by pybind11 in pycharm

Tags: python, c++, pycharm, pybind11

I'm looking for a way to use C++ code inside my python project.
For that, I'm using pybind11, and i used the following youtube videos as a tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-eIkUnCLMFc&list=PLb9uFnQyeGTcKIHNUNUUuLbRhumAZd-fy&index=1

Based on that tutorial, I've successfully created a basic C++ module and managed to run the code using python command prompt in the cmd.

Here's the C++ code:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void say_hello()
{
    printf("Hello World from C++\n");
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(pybind11module, module)
{
    module.doc() = "Pybind11Module";
    module.def("say_hello", &say_hello);
}
```

And here's the successful run in the python command prompt:
[image]

I was wondering is there a way to use the module i've created in other places as well? for example pycharm?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes, you just need to figure out how to set the `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path` for wherever you want to use the module. That's probably in PyCharm's settings somewhere

Comment: thanks @Justin, ive solved the problem, and will post the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Justin's comment, I've searched the internet for how to set a value for `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`.

Finally I found the next link:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-reloading-interpreter-paths.html

This link covers the subject: how to install, uninstall, and upgrade interpreter paths.
So, all i had to do in order to use my c++ code in python project was enter the path of the cpp module, and that solved my problem.

Comment: You should include more information in this answer rather than just linking to the documentation. Specifically, it would be much better to include a basic description of steps on how you can do this in PyCharm. Something like, "On the _Python Interpreters_ widget, open the settings, then add an interpreter path to point to the path of the cpp module" (I don't know if that's correct or not).